# committing sources from crucible to svn r

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, atlassian-crucible, svn-repository

We are using crucible for reviews. We upload the source files manually to crucible and once the review completed we will commit the files to svn from local folders.Sometimes we are missing the files or uploading a wrong file to svn. Is there any way directly commit the files to svn from crucible once the review is completed

Comment: There's no such way. Fisheye&Crucible was designed in the way to have READ ONLY access to a repositories.  I can try to write a plugin which does write to a repository, but it may be hacky and unreliable solution

Comment: thanks for the reply . What does precommit option do in crucible ?

Comment: It allows you to create a review from a patch file. It's just another type of workflows, when you want to get review feedback before committing any code to a repository. But in order to have changes in repo, you need to do it by your own. The tool won't help you in that, as I wrote READ ONLY by design.